# Web Service returning definition of response with initial value set

Tags: sql, soap, axis

So I have a simple webservice that has an input of a userid and gets a flag from a sql database (initially set to '1').

However, when I query a user with the default value of the flag (which I set to 1 in SQL Server), I get the following response:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <result xsi:type="ns1:getPWFlagResponse" xsi:nil="1" xmlns:ns1="<NamespaceURL>"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, if I change the value of the flag, I Get the correct response for all other requests:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <result>
         <result>1</result>
      </result>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

(Same for result of 0 ).

I thought that it could be that I didn't initialize something at first, however if I don't set an initial value on the PWResetFlag column in the table the webService comes back with the correct response.

Is this something with SQL server and setting default values or something on my end?

Thanks

Comment: This probably depends on your code. Please show it to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to update the question in case anyone else has had similar problems, but I have found the root source of my problem.  I was using TOAD for sql server to do my table alterations, but when I went on to the actual server and into the database, the flag was set to NULL as a default value despite me altering it to not accept nulls and applying a default value of 1.

I did the alterations directly in SQL Server on the machine which correctly applied the default value and now my webservice is working perfectly!

Thanks